# How to remove first object from array using splice in angular 8 on click everytime

Tags: angular

I have an array contains 3 objects. I want to remove first object every click.When I click button, only first time first object is removing, I need to remove every time the first object from updated array result. Here is the code below  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nuwwva?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";

  ngOnInit() {}

  clickhere() {
    const arraydata = [
      { name: "name1", value: 1 },
      { name: "name2", value: 2 },
      { name: "name3", value: 3 }
    ];
    arraydata.splice(0, 1);
    console.log(arraydata);
  }
}
```

### app.component.html

```
<button type="button" (click)="clickhere()">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Why are not using `shift`? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp

Comment: because here first object which is dynamic in my project, shift will only remove first element. First object can be second also

Comment: `I want to remove first object every click` -> that's what `shift` does.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";

  arraydata = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.arraydata = [{ name: "name1", value: 1 },
      { name: "name2", value: 2 },
      { name: "name3", value: 3 }
  }];

  clickhere() {
    this.arraydata.splice(0, 1);
    console.log(arraydata);
  }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,I want the same result but using without global variable